# Unity Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity3d, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um Quiz em Unity e estou com um erro que não consigo resolver, já pesquisei erros parecidos mas não consigo identificar, aparece essa mensagem quando estou rodando o quiz

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object GameController.Start () (at Assets/GameController.cs:39)

esse é o GameController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

public Text textoPergunta;
public Text textoPontos;
public Text textoTimer;
public Text highScoreText;

public SimpleObjectPool answerButtonObjectPool;
public Transform answerButtonParent;
public GameObject painelDePerguntas;
public GameObject painelFimRodada;

private DataController dataController;
public RoundData rodadaAtual;
private QuestionData[] questionPool;

private bool rodadaAtiva;
private float tempoRestante;
private int questionIndex;
private int playerScore;

List<int> usedValues = new List<int>();

private List<GameObject> answerButtonGameObjects = new List<GameObject>();



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {


    dataController = FindObjectOfType<DataController>();


    rodadaAtual = dataController.GetCurrentRoundData();                   //ERRO Some quando tiro essas linhas      
    questionPool = rodadaAtual.perguntas;                                 //ERRO   
    tempoRestante = rodadaAtual.limiteDeTempo;                            //ERRO

    UpdateTimer();

    playerScore = 0;
    questionIndex = 0;
    ShowQuestion();
    rodadaAtiva = true;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (rodadaAtiva)
    {
        tempoRestante -= Time.deltaTime;
        UpdateTimer();

        if (tempoRestante <= 0)
        {
            endRound();
        }
    }


}


// Funções
private void UpdateTimer()
{
    textoTimer.text = "Timer: " + Mathf.Round(tempoRestante).ToString();
}


private void ShowQuestion()
{
    RemoveAnswerButtons();

    int random = Random.Range(0, questionPool.Length);
    while (usedValues.Contains(random))
    {
        random = Random.Range(0, questionPool.Length);
    }
    QuestionData questionData = questionPool[random];
    usedValues.Add(random);
    textoPergunta.text = questionData.textoDaPergunta;


    for (int i = 0; i < questionData.respostas.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject answerButtonGameObject = answerButtonObjectPool.GetObject();

        answerButtonGameObject.transform.SetParent(answerButtonParent);

        answerButtonGameObjects.Add(answerButtonGameObject);

        AnswerButton answerButton = answerButtonGameObject.GetComponent<AnswerButton>();
        answerButton.Setup(questionData.respostas[i]);
    }
}

private void RemoveAnswerButtons()
{
    while(answerButtonGameObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        answerButtonObjectPool.ReturnObject(answerButtonGameObjects[0]);
        answerButtonGameObjects.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}

public void AnswerButtonClicked(bool estaCorreto)
{
    if (estaCorreto)
    {
        playerScore += rodadaAtual.pontosPorAcerto;
        textoPontos.text = "Score: " + playerScore.ToString();
    }

    if(questionPool.Length > questionIndex + 1)
    {
        questionIndex++;
        ShowQuestion();
    }
    else
    {
        endRound();
    }

}
    public void endRound()
    {
        rodadaAtiva = false;

    painelDePerguntas.SetActive(false);
    painelFimRodada.SetActive(true);
    }

public void ReturnToMenu()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}
```

}

Eu percebi que toda vez que eu tiro o `datacontroller.getcurrentRoundData` ele para com esse erro, mas não consigo ver onde está o erro nessa função ou nas subsequentes, pois esse `GetCurrentRoundData` está assim:

```
public RoundData GetCurrentRoundData()
{
    return todasAsRodadas[rodadaIndex];
}
```

Não sei se o erro está mesmo ai e eu que não consigo identificar, o que eu verifiquei foi que tirando as linhas da rodadaAtual ele para de dar esse erro, agora como resolver eu não sei, se está falando algo os códigos estão zipados no link abaixo do dropbox, estou seguindo um tutorial mas o código aparentemente está idêntico ao do tutorial: [link do tutorial](https://www.highlevelbr.com/quiz-game)

[link para arquivos no DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4p8y32f2z0b521x/quizGame.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. O motivo de estar dando esse erro é porque ele não acha o objeto de referência e por isso causa esse erro. Para resolver esse problema primeiro troque a linha DataController por um GameObject e deixa em público:

```
 public GameObject objeto;
```

Então na hora de chamar o objeto você usa o GetComponent<>();

```
DataController dataController = objeto.GetComponent<DataController>();
```

Pronto, assim você pode chamar os métodos do outro script, porém você vai ter que chamar ele o tempo todo em outros métodos do GameController sempre que você querer usar.

Comment: não funcionou pois o erro só some quando eu tiro as linhas relacionadas com a rodadaAtual, aquele dataController não está fazendo nenhuma diferença no erro, já tirei essas linhas pra testar, fiz isso que voce falou e continua dando exatamente o mesmo erro, tentei demonstrar mais coisas na pergunta para ver se fica mais claro

Comment: Você criou um gameobject, colocou o script DataController nele para depois fazer a chamada?

Comment: resolvido, refiz o tutorial do zero e devia ter algum erro de digitação, não consegui identificar o que foi, mas agora está rodando 100% vlw a ajuda